# $\lim \sqrt[n]{a^n + b^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I've seen some answers here for why this limit is the maximum between $a$ and $b$, but all of then included the hypothesis that $a$ and $b$ are both non negative.

It was asked to show that this limit is $\max\{a,b\}$ without any extra hypothesis. Does anyone can give me a hint of how can I do this without using that the numbers are positive? Or the hypothesis is a necessary condition?

I hope you understand the "duplicated' topic

Comment: I think that the book forgot to put a and b positive.

Comment: Then see my updated answer.

Comment: The limit exists and equals $\max\{a,b\}$ iff $\min\{a,b\}+\max\{a,b\}>0$ or $a=b=0$.

Comment: There are various kinds of trouble when we allow negatives. One example has already been mentioned. For another issue, let $b=0$ and $a=-47$. Then our expression oscillates between $-47$ and $47$.

Comment: It's simply not true unless $a,b\geq 0$.

Comment: Interesting that  $n\to -\infty $ is  $\min\{a,b\}$.

Comment: Nah, for positive numbers that's just 1/ max of the reciprocals. By rules for how negative powers work, this makes sense to give the min, @Alan

Answer (score 2):

If $a=b=-1$ then the subsequence

$$c_{2n}=\sqrt[2n]{a^{2n}+b^{2n}}=\sqrt[2n]{2}\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} 1$$

but the max is $-1$, clearly. It's also easy to see that the limit on the odd terms gives

$$\sqrt[2n+1]{a^{2n+1}+b^{2n+1}}=\sqrt[2n+1]{-2}=(-1)\cdot\sqrt[2n+1]{2}\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} -1$$

so that the limit doesn't exist because your terms are bouncing around.

---

**Addendum:** In light of your comment, we can also see why this demonstrates that you really **do** want both of $a,b\ge 0$. Even only one is insufficient as $a=-b=1$ gives the subsequence

$$c_{2n+1}=\sqrt[2n+1]{a^n+b^n}=\sqrt[2n+1]{0}\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$$

but the max is clearly $1$, and again, the overall limit doesn't even exist.

Answer (score 0):

If $a>b\geq 0$; then $\sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n}=a\sqrt[n]{1+(\frac{b}{a})^n}=ae^{\frac{1}{n}\ln(1+(\frac{b}{a})^n)}$. since $\ln(1+(\frac{b}{a})^n)\sim (\frac{b}{a})^n$ we have $\dfrac{1}{n}\ln(1+(\frac{b}{a})^n)\sim \frac{1}{n}(\frac{b}{a})^n$, hence $\dfrac{1}{n}\ln(1+(\frac{b}{a})^n)\to 0$, and $\sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n}\to a=\max(a,b)$.If  $a=b$ it is easy to show it.

Comment: If you reread the original post, the op specifically noted that this was a duplicate for positive values and asked a different question.